# Using Realtime Database orderby with multiple values in the field

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an application where people can create a postering job with jobs in multiple cities.  For example a job could contain posters in Toronto, Montreal & Chicago.  I would like to organize it using a posters array like the following

```
{
  "posters": [
    {
      "id": "axf",
      "city": "Toronto"
    },
    {
      "id": "axf",
      "city": "Montreal"
    },
    {
      "id": "axf",
      "city": "Calgary"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to filter to find all of the jobs with posters in a certain city.  Is this possible?  I could also do it in a single string like the following

```
"posters":"Toronto&Montreal&Chicago"
```

Could I use something like Regex in the real-time database orderBy query? Here is the current query

```
    .orderByChild("job/job/city").equalTo("toronto")
```

I thought about something like this

```
 .orderByChild("job/job/city").equalTo(".*Toronto.*")
```

If this doesn't exist I'll make a feature request!

Comment: Is this javascript? You can just use `matches()` right?

Comment: To understand better, are you looking for multiple where equal calls? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database has limited querying capabilities, and nothing to the point of what you're trying to do. If you want a more elaborate query API while staying within Firebase, you may want to consider using Firestore instead.

---

If staying on the Realtime Database, you'll first want to reconsider your use of an array to store data, as Firebase actively recommends against arrays, e.g. in [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

To better be able to query data in categories on Realtime Database, consider changing your data model to the way I showed here: [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)